# So i tried making a new encryption and decryption system in python

Tags: python

Im getting this: zzzzz zz zzzz zzz zz zzzz zzzz instead of the results i expected

So basically i was trying to make a new encryption and decryption type system in python and made a function and i tried to encode it like this:

```
def encode(text):
    text = str(text).replace("a", "b")
    text = str(text).replace("b", "c")
    text = str(text).replace("c", "d")
    text = str(text).replace("d", "e")
    text = str(text).replace("e", "f")
    text = str(text).replace("f", "g")
    text = str(text).replace("g", "h")
    text = str(text).replace("h", "i")
    text = str(text).replace("i", "j")
    text = str(text).replace("j", "k")
    text = str(text).replace("k", "l")
    text = str(text).replace("l", "m")
    text = str(text).replace("m", "n")
    text = str(text).replace("n", "o")
    text = str(text).replace("o", "p")
    text = str(text).replace("p", "q")
    text = str(text).replace("q", "r")
    text = str(text).replace("r", "s")
    text = str(text).replace("s", "t")
    text = str(text).replace("t", "u")
    text = str(text).replace("u", "v")
    text = str(text).replace("v", "w")
    text = str(text).replace("w", "x")
    text = str(text).replace("x", "y")
    text = str(text).replace("y", "z")
    return text

print(encode("hello me is so cool and fool lol"))
```

but instead of getting a message that has each letter different i got this output: zzzzz zz zz zz zzzz zzz zzzz zzz

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: After you replace "a"s with "b"s, what happens to those "b"s?

Comment: Oh i see the error but sadly idk how to fix it can you help me?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but the simplest change to your code is just to do what you did in reverse (though note, you don't do anything with zs)

Comment: Just process the characters one by one with a dictionary. The canonical python approach would be to use a string translation table (`maketrans`/`translate`)

Answer (score 1):

```
text = str(text).replace("a", "b") // a -> b
text = str(text).replace("b", "c") // b -> c which means a -> c
// ...
text = str(text).replace("y", "z") // result: a -> z
```

To fix this, you can use more other ways to encode the text. One way is to convert each character to its ASCII code, add a fixed value to the code to shift it, and then convert the shifted code back to a character.
Here's an example code:

```
def encode(text):
result = ""
for char in text:
    # convert character to ASCII code and add shift value
    shifted_code = ord(char) + 1
    
    # handle wrapping around from 'z' to 'a'
    if char.islower() and shifted_code > ord('z'):
        shifted_code = ord('a')
    elif char.isupper() and shifted_code > ord('Z'):
        shifted_code = ord('A')
    
    # convert shifted code back to character and append to result
    result += chr(shifted_code)
return result
```

There are more ways to save your code.
Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is replacing 'a's with 'b's, then all 'b's, including the ones you just encrypted, with 'c's. This repeats through all the letters of the alphabet, progressively replacing them all with z. It can be useful to think through what happens in each line.

You start with `"hello me is so cool and fool lol"`

and then `text = str(text).replace("a", "b")` runs, so you get `"hello me is so cool bnd fool lol"`

and then `text = str(text).replace("b", "c")` runs, so you get `"hello me is so cool cnd fool lol"`

and then `text = str(text).replace("c", "d")` runs, so you get `"hello me is so dool dnd fool lol"`

and then `text = str(text).replace("d", "e")` runs, so you get `"hello me is so eool ene fool lol"`

See the pattern?

To fix this you could store the alphabet in an array, and replace each letter in the message with the next item in the array.

```
def encode(text):
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

    output = ""

    for letter in text:
        letter_index = alphabet.index(letter)
        new_letter_index = letter_index + 1
        new_letter = alphabet[new_letter_index]
        output += new_letter

    return output
```

Or more condensed

```
def encode(text):
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

    output = ""

    for letter in text:
 
        output += alphabet[alphabet.index(letter)+1]

    return output
```

Hope this helps